# How do I center List View Webpart on SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, list-view, list-view-web-part

I have built site on SharePoint Online (Publishing site Template). I have received a request from a user to align List View Webpart to center on the custom page. currently by default when I insert webpart it show on the left side. Can anyone help advise on how do I align it to center? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new section and set section layout to **One column**.

[image]

Insert the list view web part to the new section then.